# Opening Object to include a module

Tags: ruby

I'm writing an interactive shell (just as irb) in ruby, for another language. I thought of writing all the functions regarding the shell (i.e read input and parse) in a module, then doing `class Object; include Shell; end`.

My doubt is: From my readings from *Ruby under a microscope*, I learned that in CRuby (what I'm using), when you include a module, ruby creates a copy of this module and appends it as the super class of the class that includes it, so it seems that this would waste a bit of memory, but then I looked into the kernel module, which AFAIK is included in object, and this seems okay.

Finally, the question is, Would it be a good practice to include `Shell` into `Object`?

Answer (score 0):

running `class Object; include Shell; end`

is the same as just `include Shell`, since `Object` is the default scope.

This is not bad for memory, it's a pretty fundamental behavior.

If you want to avoid working on the `Object` (global) scope, you can define a custom module that includes `Shell`:

```
class App
  include Shell
  def self.begin
    # do something with shell
  end
end
App.begin
```

though if you're making a REPL and do want your methods available on the global scope, then saying `include Shell` without a wrapper class seems a good approach.